# how to find the url from phpmyadmin

Tags: mysql, sql

how to find the url from php admin,i want to connect my java program to database, help me to get the url from phpmyadmin

[image: see the image of phpadmin]

```
public class sample_class {

    private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://db_ip:3306/sql12192006";

    private static final String user = "username";

    private static final String password = "password";

    public static void main(String args[]) {
        try {
            Class.forName("com.mysql.jdbc.Driver");
            Connection con = DriverManager.getConnection(url, user, password);
            System.out.println("Success");

        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }


}
```

Comment: What do you mean with _"find the url from phpmyadmin"_? What URL?  Why is this question tagged with PHP?  PHPMyAdmin is simply a web interface for your MySQL database. Are you talking about getting the correct URL to the MySQL-database?

Comment: In your updated image (the first image), you have `Server` under `Database Server` on the right. That's the URL to MySQL server.

Comment: you mean ql12.freemysqlhosting.net ??

Comment: Yes, `sql12.freemysqlhosting.net`. You also need to see if the user you're using can access the database from your host.

Comment: can you edit the code and post the answer ?

Comment: Try it out first. I'm not a Java dev, so I don't the correct syntax, but my guess is that this should work: `private static final String url = "jdbc:mysql://sql12.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/sql12192006";`. As I mentioned in my previous comment, this only works if the user you're using is allowed to access the database from any host.

Comment: java.sql.SQLException: No suitable driver found for jdbc:mysql://sql12.freemysqlhosting.net:3306/sql12192006

Comment: That sounds like a different issue. Make sure that you have all the drivers/libraries you need to connect to a MySQL database. As I mentioned, I'm not sure about the syntax either

Answer (score -1):

You can get the current page URL in PHP With 
$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] Public Variable.

Comment: see my question again, i want the simple line of url from phpadmin

Comment: use "jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/sql12192006 or you machine ip instead of localhost(for local configration).for live database connection use this url string jdbc:mysql://hostname:port/databasename